# How to know active audio device for sox in windows

Tags: windows, sox, soundcard

I'm trying to stream sound from my soundcard using sox's default audio device and dump it as a raw file. Unfortunately no sound is being detected.

Sox always use this as input and I think it's for linux.(correct me if i'm wrong but it doesn't really emit any sound in windows)

```
 '/dev/dsp' (ossdsp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sox -d -t wav - | lame - o.mp3
```

Just make sure the default audio in is wave out mix which can be set in sounds control panel.

Answer (score 0):

In WinXP, I downloaded SoX 14.3.0 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=10706&package_id=10619&release_id=691489), and from a command prompt I can do:

```
sox -d recfile.wav
```

which records from the soundcard.  Where do you see SoX trying to use `/dev/dsp`?